# local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm new to python I found some answers to this question, but nothing could really help me.

here a the part of code with which I have problem:

```
batch_index=0 # initializing a globale variable, I've tried with global batch_index too 
..................................

def next_Training_Batch():
    if  batch_index < len(train_data):
        batch_index = batch_index + 1
        return train_data[batch_index-1], train_labels[batch_index-1]
    else :
        shuffle_data()
        batch_index = 0
        return train_data[batch_index], train_labels[batch_index]
```

when I call the function I get the following :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment
```

I don't want to use a parameter in the function(as suggested in similar question) and to be honest I'm using number of "global" variable without have any errors, I don't get why I'm not allowed to evaluate it in the if statement? 
thanks for any hint !

Comment: @chris_Rands I guess I did, the rest of the code does not use batch_index nor anything related to the function

Comment: BTW, it's a good idea to avoid using modifiable globals: they make the code less modular and therefore harder to debug and to modify.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `global batch_index` to the beginning of the function and it will know that you're referring to the global variable not a local one.

```
batch_index=0 # initializing a globale variable, I've tried with global batch_index too 
...

def next_Training_Batch():
    global batch_index
    if batch_index < len(train_data):
        batch_index = batch_index + 1
        return train_data[batch_index - 1], train_labels[batch_index - 1]
    else:
        shuffle_data()
        batch_index = 0
        return tain_data[batch_index], train_labels[batch_index]
```

Comment: Thanks Moses, I was struggling!

Comment: Thanks and no worries

Comment: I see that the question has been answered but I have a doubt . I tried a sample code on my machine . The error only occurs if we do assignment , and not if we use the `batch_index` only in `if` condition . Why is that ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands : try assigning some value to that variable , You should see the error then

Comment: @Abhimanyusingh You can _read_ (and even mutate) a global variable without having a `global` directive in the function, but if you perform an assignment to that name **anywhere** inside the function body then the interpreter assumes that the name refers to a local variable, not the global one.

Comment: @PM2Ring . Thanks  ! That seems counter intuitive though . Guess Ill have to read up on this .

Comment: @Abhimanyusingh If you want to discuss this topic, come over to [the SO Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Answer (score 2):

Use the global keyword that creates the copy of the variable

```
def next_Training_Batch():
    global batch_index
    if  batch_index < len(train_data):
        batch_index = batch_index + 1
        return train_data[batch_index-1], train_labels[batch_index-1]
    else :
        shuffle_data()
        batch_index = 0
        return tain_data[batch_index], train_labels[batch_index]
```

but still train_data is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Use **global** inside the function say global batch_index

batch_index=0 # initializing a globale variable, I've tried with global batch_index too

```
def next_Training_Batch():
    global batch_index
    if  batch_index < len(train_data):
        batch_index = batch_index + 1
        return train_data[batch_index-1], train_labels[batch_index-1]
    else :
        shuffle_data()
        batch_index = 0
        return tain_data[batch_index], train_labels[batch_index]
```